# Android drawable: Unknown resource type @drawable-nodpi

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I created a new **Android Resource** Directory `drawable-nodpi` inside of **res** and placed my a png image inside, but when I try to reference it with the code below, it returns an error of

`unknown resource type @drawable-nodpi`.

What am I doing wrong? I works fine when I place it into `@drawable` but the image was `too large to be uploaded into a texture`. I am using Android Studio 2.1.2

> android:src="@drawable-nodpi/java"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `@drawable-nodpi/java`. It should be `@drawable/java`. Android will **automatic** select the source with device's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are typically these type of resources directories you can create as per the structure proposed for resources drawables in android

drawable

drawable-hdpi

drawable-mdpi

drawable-ldpi

drawable-xhdpi

drawable-hdpi

So if you want to put drawable that automatically taken as per resolution of device that is drawable folder you should use,their is no such things as per structure as drawable-nodpi